# Spark java.io.IOException due to unknown reason

Tags: apache-spark

I'm getting the following exception while running a Spark job. The job gets stuck at the same stage every time. The stage is a SQL query. I don't see any other exception in either Driver or Executor logs

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This exception is wrapped between these errors:

```
ERROR client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from hostname.domain.com/ip is closed
```

The only thing I could find in the executor logs was:

```
INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Memory used in task 12302
INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter@462e08e3: 32.0 MB
INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@41bed570: 2.4 GB
INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: 0 bytes of memory were used by task 12302 but are not associated with specific consumers
INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: 2634274570 bytes of memory are used for execution and 1826540 bytes of memory are used for storage
INFO sort.UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 197 spilling sort data of 512.0 MB to disk (0  time so far)
```

But I don't believe this is an issue due to memory. The job completes successfully in a different environment with the same amount of data.

Here's my `spark-submit` :

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster\
--conf spark.speculation=true \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=200 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=16G \
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=$0.3 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=2G \
--conf spark.driver.cores=4 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1638 \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=1G \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
--class com.test.TestClass Test.jar
```

I did read some articles here and there regarding a similar exception which point out towards increasing the heartbeat interval and network timeout. But I couldn't find a definitive answer.

How can I run this job successfully?

Comment: I'll assume that `hostname.domain.com/ip` has been redacted, right?

Comment: Perhaps sharing the code could help, it looks like you are shuffling a lot.

Comment: The SQL query is too long to add here but yes you are right, it does involve joins with 6 different tables. Data volume is not extremely huge though. 1 million per table probably. Few columns so the shuffle size should be less, right? And yes, the hostname is redacted. It is actually the executor address. the application requests 100+ executor then only kills exactly 100 executors everytime. While the others are idle too, since no activity happens after this exception is thrown except the killing of idle executors.

Comment: If you have a lot of joins you may want to consider the option to leverage bucketing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BD-Vv-ViBw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was being caused due to an issue with the data.

The driving table for all the left joins, had empty string `''` as data in one of the columns which was being used to join to another table. Similariy, the other table also had a lot of empty strings for that particular column.

This was leading in a cross-join and since the number of rows were too many, the job was getting hung indefinitely.

Adding a filter to the right table, helped in solving the issue:

```sql
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  LEFT_TABLE LT
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT
      *
    FROM
      RIGHT_TABLE
    WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN)) <> 0 ) RT
ON
  LT.PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN = RT.PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN
```